# How to emit event when Asset have been created?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

i faced with some problem:
When I create asset from my nodejs app and then try to get asset list but there is no new asset in the list yet. So I thought that better to subscribe on event to get updates, but can't find how to emit event on asset creation

Answer (score 2):

You can use the runtime `emit` method to emit events from TP functions. This is described here:

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/business-network/publishing-events.html

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/applications/subscribing-to-events.html